# How to reload programatically a module contained within a package in python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

So far I've seen the answer for Python2 however it doesn't work on Python3, I want to be able to always get the latest changes in a module that lives in a package every time the code runs without reopening a new interpreter every time. Since modules seems to be loaded just once for performance purposes as specified in documentation,I would like to be able to force a load in the modules programatically right before starting my program. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not a fan of answering my own questions, I think in this case totally worth to mention it since seems to be quiet useful, in order to reload a module that you previously modified without having to restart the whole interpreter, just programatically forcing the modules (contained within a package) to get the latest changes this is the way to go:

```
import com.your.package.YourModule as MyModuleInPackage
import imp
imp.reload(MyModuleInPackage)
```

Notice that trying to use `imp.reload(com.your.package.YourModule)` causes an error, so the way to go is by having an Alias for the fully quialified name of the module and use it in the reload function to work properly...

Hope this helps.

Regards!